# Autologin while using Firebase Email and Password Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I am using Firebase authentication with email and password on my website for authentication.
But i get a token which expires after 1 hour and the user is logged out.
Please help me with some way i can keep the user logged in.

EDIT: I have set up the authentication system on the backend using cloud functions

Comment: The client SDK for Firebase Auth automatically refreshes the token for you every hour as needed - there is no automatic logout.  Without seeing your code, we don't know if you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: Hi... i have set up the authentication on cloud functions for firebase..So.. i send a post request to the cloud functions , which in turn handles the athentication

Comment: I have set the authentication on the backend so that my api key remains hidden